# Help defining a logic environment

Tags: macros, equations, logic

I've been squandering a number of hours on trying to define a new environment for writing logical formulae (for linguistics) in a simplified way, but to no avail.
The goal is to have a math (boldmath in fact) environment which automatically sets sequences of two or more letters (not characters in general) in \textbf{} (because of better kerning) but everything else, including parentheses, commands and in particular single letter variables in regular math font.

Example: 
input:

```
\begin{mylogicenvironment}
\lambda x_2.\exists y[ man(x) \& know(\langle x_2,x\rangle)]
\end{mylogicenvironment}
```

output equivalent to that of:

```
\boldmath $\lambda x_2.\exists y[ \textbf{man}(x) \& \textbf{know}(\langle x_2, x\rangle\)]$
```

Bonus if I can define shortcuts so that I can write e.g. E for `\exists`, L for `\lambda` etc.
Double bonus if [], (), <> could automatically convert to `\left( \right)` etc., so that

input:

```
\begin{mylogicenvironment}
Lx_2.Ey[ man(x) \& know(<x_2,x>)]
\end{mylogicenvironment}
```

output equivalent to that of:

```
\boldmath $\lambda x_2.\exists y\left[ \textbf{man}(x) \& \textbf{know}\left(\left\langle x_2, \right\rangle\)\right]$
```

(I know how to get the bonus parts by themselves, just curious about combining them with the other stuff.)
I'd be particularly curious about solutions without regular expressions.

Comment: You almost certainly have [an XY-problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean/2450). Why not use a font with better kerning? Would, for example, `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}` work for you?

Comment: Very good, didn't know about that one! This particular package didn't work for me (PDFLatex) but i found a similar workaround. I'd still be curious how something like what I talked about would be written by the pros...